# Book Value From Price/Book

Tags: investing, yahoo-finance, book-value

Yahoo Finance gives the `Price/Book` and I'm guessing that `Book` is *book value*?  I'm trying to get the `Book Value` from this equation, so is the below equation correct:

`Book Value` = `Price` divided by `Price/Book`

When fractions divided, they invert, so the prices will cancel leaving book.  But since it's not clear if `Book` is `Book Value`, I'm not sure if this derives `Book Value`.

[Example with Facebook](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/key-statistics?p=FB):

`Price` is 180.  `Price/Book` is 6.58.  `Book Value` is 27.35?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your math is correct, and gives you book value *per share*. So to get the total "book value" you need to multiply by the number of shares outstanding.

Since FB has about 2.98B shares outstanding, that implies a total book value of about $81.5 billion.

Which is fairly close to the published book value (assets - liabilities) in their latest quarterly balance sheet of $79.3B

Comment: Ah, ok. So Yahoo's `Price/Book` is actually `Price/Book-Value-Per-Share`.

Comment: Yes, although the "per share" is implicit in both the price and the book value. (same for P/E, price/sales, and other similar ratios)